# How to activate 'Do not disturb' when connected to a specific Bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, automation, do-not-disturb

I want to benefit from Androids "Do not disturb"-feature while driving. My idea is to activate the "Do not disturb"-feature, when my phone connects to my cars bluetooth. If enabled no notifications would appear which is a huge advantage for me because this results in less distractions while driving.

"Do not disturb"-feature is already configured properly. If manually activated I do not get any distracting notifications. My question is how to automatically activate the feature when a bluetooth connection is established.

I'm using a Oneplus 6 with Android 10. My car does not support Android Auto.

Bonus points for solutions that don't require to install further apps. Unfortunately I think that is not possible right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed, you need an extra app and in this case [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) app.

[MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) is easy to learn and free up to 5 macros. You need one macro

**Trigger**

Bluetooth event → Device connected → your car device

**Action**

Priority mode/Do not disturb → select one of the options -  Allow priority notifications or Block all

Name and save the macro

---

You would need to manually disable DND mode once you are out of your car BT range or create another macro where the trigger would be BT event → Device disconnected and in the action whatever you wish, likely allow all

Comment: You can test this with any BT device like ear phones –